# TCPDF create move-able "box" with text without using ln settings

Tags: tcpdf

I am trying to create a bit of a unique table in TCPDF as shown below:

[image]
Getting the captions, headers and rows setup is easy. The hard part is the "bar".

The bar needs a few things:

- Editable X-position
- Text

Originally I was trying to use MultiCell; however, I got some weird behavior as shown below:

Multi-Cell:
[image: Multi-Cell Weird Behavior]

I believe this is because of the `ln` settings. If we look at my code you can see that I am trying to create a Cell and then a MultiCell inside of it. Both of these use the have the `ln` setting to put the next cell below. 
I tried setting the MultiCell's ln to 0 (to the right) but it had no visible change.

```
//multi cell
// extend TCPF with custom functions
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    // SCC table
    public function SCCTable($headers,$rows) {
        // Colors, line width and bold font
        $this->SetFillColor(0,128,128);
        $this->SetTextColor(0);
        $this->SetDrawColor(0);
        $this->SetLineWidth(0.3);
        $this->SetFont('', 'B');
        // Header
        $num_headers = count($headers);
        for($i = 0; $i < $num_headers; ++$i) {
            $this->Cell(
                $headers[$i]->width, 
                $headers[$i]->height, 
                $headers[$i]->text, 
                1, 
                0, 
                'C', 
                1
            );
        }
        $this->Ln();
        // Color and font restoration
        $this->SetFillColor(255);
        $this->SetTextColor(0);
        $this->SetFont('');
        // Data
        $fill = 0;
        $num_rows = count($rows);
        for($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; ++$i){
            $this->Cell(//Row
                $headers[$i]->width * $num_headers, //Row width should be the sum of all header width. 
                $rows[$i]->height,
                //Row's Text
                $this->MultiCell(
                    $rows[$i]->width, 
                    $rows[$i]->height, 
                    $rows[$i]->text, 
                    0, //Border
                    "C", //Text Align
                    false, //fill, determines if the background is painted or transparent (false). 
                    2, //ln, 1 = Next cell starts at beginning of new line.
                    $rows[$i]->x, 
                    $rows[$i]->y 
                ), 
                1, //Border
                2, //ln, 1 = Next cell starts at beginning of new line.
                "L" //text align
            );
        }
    }
}
```

After this I found out about `TextField`. When I tried this I got just as weird behavior...

[image]

```
//text field
// extend TCPF with custom functions
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    // SCC table
    public function SCCTable($headers,$rows) {
        // Colors, line width and bold font
        $this->SetFillColor(0,128,128);
        $this->SetTextColor(0);
        $this->SetDrawColor(0);
        $this->SetLineWidth(0.3);
        $this->SetFont('', 'B');
        // Header
        $num_headers = count($headers);
        for($i = 0; $i < $num_headers; ++$i) {
            $this->Cell(
                $headers[$i]->width, 
                $headers[$i]->height, 
                $headers[$i]->text, 
                1, 
                0, 
                'C', 
                1
            );
        }
        $this->Ln();
        // Color and font restoration
        $this->SetFillColor(255);
        $this->SetTextColor(0);
        $this->SetFont('');
        // Data
        $fill = 0;
        $num_rows = count($rows);
        for($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; ++$i){
            $this->Cell(//Row
                $headers[$i]->width * $num_headers, //Row width should be the sum of all header width. 
                $rows[$i]->height,
                //Row's Text
                $this->TextField(
                    $rows[$i]->text,
                    $rows[$i]->width, 
                    $rows[$i]->height, 
                    [],
                    [],
                    $rows[$i]->x, 
                    $rows[$i]->y                                                                    
                ), 
                1, //Border
                2, //ln, 1 = Next cell starts at beginning of new line.
                "L" //text align
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I thought of using the `Rect` function to create a rectangle and `Text` to the draw the text. Using variables I could "glue" the Text to the Rectangle; however, the textfield uses the ln setting as well; furthermore, looking at the actual code there is this line:

```
$this->Cell(0, 0, $txt, $border, $ln, $align, $fill, $link, $stretch, $ignore_min_height, $calign, $valign);
```

Seeing as it creates a cell, then it should run into the same problem as MultiCell, as the only difference between Cell and MultiCell in my case is the ability to change the x-position from the left border.

So I'm stuck with this question: How can I draw a "box" that has text and can be pushed along horizontally?
How this is done is not that important except that images aren't an option.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I didn't actually need to have the original row. I could just make due with the "bar".

[image]

```
$this->MultiCell(
    $rows[$i]->width, 
    $rows[$i]->height, 
    $rows[$i]->text, 
    1, //Border
    "C", //Text Align
    true, //fill, determines if the background is painted (true) or transparent (false). 
    2, //ln, 1 = Next cell starts at beginning of new line.
    $rows[$i]->x, 
    $rows[$i]->y 
);
```

Though with that said it would still be nice to know how to do with rows...